# How to detect and increase the space between two lines in an image of text using opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

If the initial image is like this(above) then I can **successfully** introduce space between the 2 lines and get this image(below)
[image]

using the code below:

```
import os
import cv2
def space_between_lines_and_skewness_correction(file_path):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.expanduser(file_path))
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    th, threshed = cv2.threshold(grey, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    pts = cv2.findNonZero(threshed)
    ret = cv2.minAreaRect(pts)
    (cx, cy), (w, h), ang = ret

    if w < h:
        w, h = h, w
        ang += 90
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cx, cy), ang, 1.0)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(threshed, M, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
    hist = cv2.reduce(rotated, 1, cv2.REDUCE_AVG).reshape(-1)
    th = 2
    H, W = img.shape[:2]
    delimeter = [y for y in range(H - 1) if hist[y] <= th < hist[y + 1]]
    arr = []
    y_prev = 0
    y_curr = 0
    for y in delimeter:
        y_prev = y_curr
        y_curr = y
        arr.append(rotated[y_prev:y_curr, 0:W])

    arr.append(rotated[y_curr:H, 0:W])
    space_arr = np.zeros((10, W))
    final_img = np.zeros((1, W))

    for im in arr:
        v = np.concatenate((space_arr, im), axis=0)
        final_img = np.concatenate((final_img, v), axis=0)
    return final_img
```

The above code will remove skewness and introduce space.
**But for few cases, the above code doesn't work.** 
These are cases like:[image]
The output for the image is 
[image]

How to handle cases such as this?

**Note:**
I tried to resize to a bigger size and do pixel by pixel iteration and building a custom algorithm for this case, but it is taking a huge amount of time to solve and sometimes giving memory error.

**Please Note: The input of the above code is actually the inverse image(white background) of the image provided here**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
def detect_letters(img):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # just to remove noise
    thresh_val, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    num_labels, _, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh)

    for i in range(num_labels):
        leftmost_x = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]
        topmost_y = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]
        width = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
        height = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]

        # enclose all detected components in a blue rectangle
        cv2.rectangle(img, (leftmost_x, topmost_y), (leftmost_x + width, topmost_y + height), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("window", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
```

Input:
[image]

Output:

[image]

The main intent of the above solution is just to get an enclosing rectangle around every letter.

Now all you need to do is shift all those letters above or below or wherever you want to.

For example, see how the football was shifted in the following link : https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html

As you know the topmost and bottom-most y coordinate for every letter now, you can see how much far away they currently are and if they are very close just shift the letter as in the above link.

The letters on the same line will have very little difference in their vertex coordinates or centroids. You can have a tolerence range to spot out all those letters.

If any issues, feel free to ask.